# links are not appearing to the auth user

Tags: laravel

Im using the laravel auth. When a guest user access to the app we should see the links:

```
 Item 1, Item 2, Login and Item 3
```

When he login, for example with the name John, he should see the links:

```
Item 1, Item 2, John, Item 3
```

But its not working, when the user logins just appears the links:

```
John, Item 3
```

The Item1 and Item2 dont appears. Do you know why?

```
<ul class="navbar-nav">

  @guest
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="">Item 1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Item 2</a>
  </li>


  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('login') }}">Login</a>
  </li>
  @else
  <li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="userDropdown"  data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i> {{ Auth::user()->name }}
    </a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="userDropdown">
      <a class="dropdown-item text-gray" href="{!! url('/item1'); !!}">Login Item 1</a>
      <div class="dropdown-divider text-gray"></div>
      <a class="dropdown-item text-gray" href="{{ route('logout') }}"
         onclick="event.preventDefault();
                  document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
        Logout
      </a>
      <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
      </form>
    </div>
  </li>
  @endguest

  <li class="nav-item d-none d-lg-block px-0">
    <a class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm font-weight-bold" href="">
      Item 3 
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@guest` is used for non-login user.

You should change it to

```
<ul class="navbar-nav">


  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="">Item 1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Item 2</a>
  </li>

  @guest
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('login') }}">Login</a>
  </li>
  @endguest

  @if(\Auth::check())
  <li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="userDropdown"  data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i> {{ Auth::user()->name }}
    </a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="userDropdown">
      <a class="dropdown-item text-gray" href="{!! url('/item1'); !!}">Login Item 1</a>
      <div class="dropdown-divider text-gray"></div>
      <a class="dropdown-item text-gray" href="{{ route('logout') }}"
         onclick="event.preventDefault();
                  document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
        Logout
      </a>
      <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
      </form>
    </div>
  </li>
  @endif

  <li class="nav-item d-none d-lg-block px-0">
    <a class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm font-weight-bold" href="">
      Item 3 
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Everything between `@guest` and `@else` will only appear if the user is not logged in.

Putting `Item 1` and `Item 2` right after the `@guest` directive means, you want `Item 1` and `Item 2` to appear if the user it is not logged in

Change you code to

```
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="">Item 1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Item 2</a>
  </li>

  @guest

  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('login') }}">Login</a>
  </li>

  @else
  <li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="userDropdown"  data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i> {{ Auth::user()->name }}
    </a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="userDropdown">
      <a class="dropdown-item text-gray" href="{!! url('/item1'); !!}">Login Item 1</a>
      <div class="dropdown-divider text-gray"></div>
      <a class="dropdown-item text-gray" href="{{ route('logout') }}"
         onclick="event.preventDefault();
                  document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
        Logout
      </a>
      <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
      </form>
    </div>
  </li>
  @endauth

  <li class="nav-item d-none d-lg-block px-0">
    <a class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm font-weight-bold" href="">
      Item 3 
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

You can read more about those directives [here](https://arjunphp.com/laravel-5-5-new-blade-directives-auth-guest/)

Comment: You should explain *what* you changed, and *why*.

Answer (score 0):

Change it to:

```
<li class="nav-item">
   <a class="nav-link" href="">Item 1</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
   <a class="nav-link" href="#">Item 2</a>
</li>

@guest
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('login') }}">Login</a>
    </li>
@endguest

@auth
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        ....
    </li>
@endauth


<li class="nav-item d-none d-lg-block px-0">
    <a class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm font-weight-bold" href="">
        Item 3 
    </a>
</li>
```